# Dynamically add files for localization C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resx

I need a help in localizing my Wpf .net 3.5 application. I am going to give only the exe file to my cient with which he will create setup for his users. My client wants to add files for localization by himself.

The general method of localization is creating .resx files for each languages and set the language in CurrentUICulture. but since, he cant use resgen tool to create resource files, I want to know the best method to let him add files in txt,excel,xml format to make the localization.

PS: reading through stream and assigning the key is the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot use the resgen Tool a simple textfile wit Key-Value Pairs would be the simplest way. And if you just staying with simple strings you should use just this. Name them after the default convention with the language in the name to identify to correct file to load and write yourself a custom `resourceManager` that load this files at startup or on demand into a Dictionary to access them.

***Edit:***

I go a bit more in details about this...

> I would create a resource manager that
>   has static accessors for all used
>   resourcefiles where just the fallback
>   resource is static typed. I guess your
>   language is defined at startup so just
>   load the fallback and the defined
>   language files each into a dictionary
>   and both dictionaries in a static
>   typed for this resource type.  Use a
>   GetString("name", Culture) to load a
>   string. You can do the lookups for the
>   culture in the resource dictionary and
>   if one key is missing do a fallback to
>   the static one.
>
> **Edit II:**
>
> You can ZIP the text-files using one
>   of the .Net libraries out there to
>   prevent anyone from open and change
>   the content. For additional security
>   you can also add a password to the
>   zip. So you end up with smaller files
>   plus the ability to modify the files
>   with any ZIP program. For sure you
>   should also change the file
>   extension.

Hope this helps

Comment: @sra, As you said, I am going to use simple key-value pair strings, but the ResourceManager loads only the files with .resource right? or can it read .txt/.xml too?

Comment: @Coder323 the resourceManager expects a assembly with embedded resources and will fail on all other. The XML structure that you see in a project is just a reference for the compiler which resources to embed and where to find them plus the class with the static accessors. So yes, you will need to write your own one. But it should be quite simple in your case as a described above.

Comment: @sra, I can write custom code to read the xml file and assign to the control's content but what if the user of my client may change the simple xml file?

Comment: @Coder323 Do you want that or do you don't want that? You can rename the extension and if you want zip it using one of the open source .net libraries. And if you want to make it really hard zip with password.

Comment: @sra, I dont want that to happen. Ok I can ecrypt using some algorithm. Thanks for editing your post, I will try this one.

Comment: @Coder323 Use a packer instead. So if there is a need to change them you may do this with any zip program. Or at least I think so....